# Selecting Options from a Drop Down Menu in C# using Selenium

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I am trying to select a specific option in a drop down menu.  My current code highlights the selection I want, but moves on and does not keep the value in the field after "selecting" it. I want to grab the value "Medical." Currently I am using:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("DISPLAY_CoverageType"));
SelectElement selector = new SelectElement(element);
selector.SelectByText("Medical");
```

The List I am pulling from looks like:

```
<option value="">Please Select One</option>
<option value="Medical">Medical</option>
<option value="Hospital">Hospital</option>
<option value="Dental">Dental</option>
<option value="Vision">Vision</option>
```

This highlights my selection in blue, but does not keep it selected when the drop down menu closes.  Any advice?

Comment: Just a wild guess, what if you would issue the `element.Click();` before selecting the option?

Comment: Another guess: call `selector.SelectByText("Medical");` two times in a row.

Comment: @alexce Thank you!  I have actually tried both of these options already.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use css selector to bypass the `SelectElement` class and find the option directly.

```
string option = "Medical";
By css = By.CssSelector("Select>option[value='" + option + "']");
driver.FindElement(css).Click();
```

Comment: I will give it a shot and get back to you!

Comment: Seems like this just gives me the same result as using the `Select Element` class. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Is this a public site and we can reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use below line

```
 selector.selectByValue("Medical");
```

Instead of

```
 selector.SelectByText("Medical");
```

Let me know is it working or not.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference, both cases do not get me the result I am looking for : /

Answer (score 0):

Apparently going the repetitive and "easy" route was the correct way the entire time.  This code helped me pass my tests:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Name("DISPLAY_CoverageType")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[4]/select/option[3]")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[4]/select/option[3]")).Click();
```

Thanks to @alecxe for the idea of repeating calls.